# Output result of heavy calculation in Vert.x with back-pressure

Tags: java, rx-java, vert.x

The application in question handles requests from clients which then requires a lot of calculation on the server side. This calculation is done piece-by-piece, so if the client is slow to read, this calculation should not progress (the calculation should respond to back-pressure).

The calculation is now represented as a `Supplier<Buffer>`, in which the `get()` call might take a long time and needs to be called multiple times until it responds with `null` (no more data). The `get()` should be called in a separate thread-pool (which is shared with other requests), and should only be called if the client is really able to accept the data.

My current code is:

```java
ReadStream<Buffer> readStream = new MyComplicatedReadStream(supplier, executor)
   .exceptionHandler(request::fail)
   .endHandler(x -> request.response().end());
Pump.pump(readStream, request.response())).start();
```

I've made a custom implementation of `ReadStream` to do this, which sort-of works, but is long, clunky and has synchronization issues.

Instead of fixing that, **I wonder if there is a idiomatic way in vert.x / rx to implement / instantiate a `MyComplicatedReadStream`**. So, for a `Supplier<Buffer>` and an `ExecutorService` get a `ReadStream<Buffer>` which executes `get()` with the given executor and doesn't generate if it is paused.

Answer (score 1):

I have near 0 experience with vert.x but I do have some experience with rxjava. So there might be a better way to do this but from rxjava perspective you can make use of `generate` method to create 'cold' flowables which only generate items on demand. I believe in this case when the stream is paused, no additional calls to `supplier.get()` will be made as there is no 'demand'

using kotlin syntax here but I think you can derive the java version easily.

```kotlin
Flowable.generate<Buffer> { emitter ->
  val nextValue = supplier.get()
  if (nextValue == null) {
      emitter.onComplete()
  } else {
      emitter.onNext(nextValue)
  }
}.subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(executor)) // this will make the above callback run in the given executor
```

Since it seems that the supplier is holding some state, you may in some cases want to generate a 'new supplier' for each consumer, in which case you can use the overload of the generate method that allows specifying another callback to get an instance of the state (supplier in your case). http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#generate-java.util.concurrent.Callable-io.reactivex.functions.BiConsumer-

Looks like then you can convert the flowable to a read stream:

```
ReadStream<Buffer> readStream = FlowableHelper.toReadStream(observable);
```

based on the docs here: https://vertx.tk/docs/vertx-rx/java2/#_read_stream_support